# Read a XML node using vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have a small XML stream that I can't figure out how to read two of the first nodes (TotalCount and Offset).
the XML file is structured like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    -<SearchResultOfApiProject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <TotalCount>3986</TotalCount>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
     <Limit>50</Limit>
     -<Items>
     -<ApiProject>
     <ProjectNumber>1R01DA034054-01A1</ProjectNumber>
     <Fy>2013</Fy>
     </ApiProject>
     -<ApiProject>
     <ProjectNumber>5T32DK083262-05</ProjectNumber>
     <Fy>2013</Fy>
     </ApiProject>
     -<ApiProject>
     <ProjectNumber>5K08CA142904-04</ProjectNumber>
     <Fy>2013</Fy>
     </ApiProject>
     </Items>
    </SearchResultOfApiProject>
```

I can read the full XML file using:

```
       Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
       doc.LoadXml(xmlString)
       Dim DocumentNodes As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ApiProject")
```

And then loop the nodes but I can't figure out how to read the TotalCount and Offset nodes in the root

Answer (score 0):

I got it 
          TotalCount = doc.SelectSingleNode("SearchResultOfApiProject/TotalCount").InnerText